# WPF Listbox w/ DataTemplate Binding Issue

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, datatemplate

I'm trying to create a `ListBox` with a custom data template but the bindings seem to be wrong. When I try to add items to the list with the *PacketItem* template they are added, but the text in the three *HexItem* textboxes remains blank. When I set the item template of the listbox directly to the *HexItem* data template that works fine. It only has problems when nested in the *PacketItem* data template.

I'm sure this is a simple fix, it seems like when the template is nested it doesn't know where to look for the text bindings. I'm thinking  binding to a relative source to get the data context from a parent would work, but that seems like the wrong way to do it.

Revised XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="wpfPacketBox.ctlPacketBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfPacketBox"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PacketItem">
            <Expander IsExpanded="True"
                      d:DesignWidth="600">
                <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="PacketNum" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Source" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Dest" />
                            <TextBlock Text="PacketID (FF0A)" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                <Expander.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="65*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Offset}"
                                         FontFamily="Courier New"
                                         Foreground="Blue"
                                         Background="#FFCCCCCC"
                                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                         BorderThickness="0" />
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Hex}"
                                         FontFamily="Courier New"
                                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                         BorderThickness="0" />
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Ascii}"
                                         FontFamily="Courier New"
                                         Background="#FFCCCCCC"
                                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                         BorderThickness="0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Expander.ContentTemplate>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Packets}"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PacketItem}"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace wpfTester.UserControls
{
    public partial class test : UserControl
    {
        public ObservableCollection<clsPacket> Packets;

        public test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Packets = new ObservableCollection<clsPacket>();
            PacketListBox.ItemsSource = Packets;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Packets.Add(new clsPacket() { Offset = i, Hex = "00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77", Ascii = "ABCDEFGH" });
            }
        }
    }

    public class clsPacket
    {
        public long Offset { get; set; }
        public String Hex { get; set; }
        public String Ascii { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Solution

After some digging I found the solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/634fffa3-7e70-4cc3-9a1c-5405e4747e2a/). The problem was the expander. I was setting the header/content templates of the expander. But never specified the Header/Content it self. Here's the modified expander tag that fixed my problem.

```
<Expander IsExpanded="True" Header="{Binding}" Content="{Binding}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found the solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/634fffa3-7e70-4cc3-9a1c-5405e4747e2a/). The problem was the expander. I was setting the header/content templates of the expander. But never specified the Header/Content it self. Here's the modified expander tag that fixed my problem.

```
<Expander IsExpanded="True" Header="{Binding}" Content="{Binding}">
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I have totally the same problem as you and solved now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `DataTemplates` `DataType`(clsPacket) for the for it to resolve the bindings.

Im not sure what the other `DataTemplate` is for, but this should point you in the right direction to get your bindings working correctly.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication11.test"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication11"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:clsPacket}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="65*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Offset}"
                             FontFamily="Courier New"
                             Foreground="Blue"
                             Background="#FFCCCCCC"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap"
                             BorderThickness="0" />
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Hex}"
                             FontFamily="Courier New"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap"
                             BorderThickness="0" />
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Ascii}"
                             FontFamily="Courier New"
                             Background="#FFCCCCCC"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap"
                             BorderThickness="0" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Packets}"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

code:

```
namespace WpfApplication11
{
    public partial class test : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<clsPacket> _packets = new ObservableCollection<clsPacket>();

        public test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Packets.Add(new clsPacket() { Offset = i, Hex = "00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77", Ascii = "ABCDEFGH" });
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<clsPacket> Packets
        {
            get { return _packets; }
            set { _packets = value; }
        }
    }

    public class clsPacket
    {
        public long Offset { get; set; }
        public String Hex { get; set; }
        public String Ascii { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems much cleaner but, I think it still doesn't solve my problem, or I just can't get it to work properly with the nested template.  Here's revised xaml to clarify what I'm trying to do. I tried using 'DataType="{x:Type local:clsPacket}' with the *PacketItem* template but that doesn't work.